# How do I import Excel data into a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-2007

I have a table `mileage_registrants` which keeps users registration data. It has a field `department` which is `NULL` for all users now. I want to insert department data from a `.xlsx` file into table `department`. There are one thousand records so it is horrible for me to insert them by hand.

Is there anyway for me to get this done quickly?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to PhpMyAdmin, you may want to export your xlsx to CSV format, then import it using PhpMyAdmin import tool.

Beware of the encoding though!

Comment: thanks, Lauren. there are many fields in table mileage_registrants, but I only want to insert field department. Is that possible to do that with the method you mentioned?

Comment: I saw the import tool of phpmyadmin. How does it match each user with each department. I don't see the option in import tool to do that

Comment: @AlexHu yep: first export the table from mysql with phpmyadmin. Then make your edits in this xls/csv file, save it to csv. Finally reimport it in mysql. (backup your table before!)

Comment: users' data already exists in the table. I just want to insert their department information. So I think this method wouldn't work for my case. thank you anyway

Comment: I do not see why you couldn't :) Just export your full table, modify it using excell then reimport it into your base.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it via excel itselfe.
Here you can find a quick tutorials of you to interact with excel from mysql

http://www.heritage-tech.net/908/inserting-data-into-mysql-from-excel-using-vba/
http://www.heritage-tech.net/267/interfacing-with-mysql-via-excel/
http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html

**It is highly recommended to do a dry run before running on production**

Comment: thanks fatnjazzy. I will try your method and let you know if I have any question

Comment: Thanks fatnjazzy. Since users data already exists in table mileage_registrants, I just need to insert their department info and do a automatically match according to their user_id.